# Slicing from text file

Tags: php, arrays, regex, php-5.3

I have a .txt file in this format:

```
Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-98765-4321098-API

Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-12345-6789012-API

Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-23456-7890123-API

Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-01234-5678901-API
```

I need to end up with an array like this :

```
[ZA-98765-4321098-API, ZA-12345-6789012-API, etc]
```

I've tried some stuff in python but I realized I don't have it installed in the computer ( been using repl.it ) is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: What was your python implementation? Should be able to use `preg_match_all`...

Comment: I removed all the "Order pushed to ZA!" lines manually, used `x.splitlines()` and then sliced them.. but it didn't look good..

Comment: You didn't use a regex? You could probably use the same approach in PHP.

Comment: How do u split multi-lines in php ?

Comment: Could use: `$input_array = explode("\n", $input);`

Comment: This could easily be done from your command line as well: `awk -F: '$2 {print $2}' foo.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple regex:

```
preg_match_all('/Order Number: (.*)/', file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt'), $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

If you want to capture the newlines at the end then one possible pattern is:

```
/Order Number: (.*\n?)/
```

Comment: Don't need to replace with MP.. was a typo :P

Comment: Is there a way to format it with newline between each occurrence?

Comment: @Onilol You can add an optional new character line in the capture group, `\n?`. It'd probably be better to append the new line character when outputting this array though.

Comment: Edited to capture newlines.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
<?php

function getBetween($a, $b, $c) {
    $y = explode($b, $a);
    $len = sizeof($y);
    $arr = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $el = explode($c, $y[$i]);
        $arr[] = $el[0];
    }
    return $arr;
}

$data = 'Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-98765-4321098-API

Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-12345-6789012-API

Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-23456-7890123-API

Order pushed to ZA!
Order Number: ZA-01234-5678901-API';

$final = getBetween($data, 'ZA-', '-API');
foreach ($final as &$value)
    $value = 'ZA-' . $value . '-API';

print_r($final);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/9250fbf563adb0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => MP-98765-4321098-API
    [1] => MP-12345-6789012-API
    [2] => MP-23456-7890123-API
    [3] => MP-01234-5678901-API
)
```

Comment: I edited the code to support versions below 5.4. See if this works out.

Comment: Oh and I realized that you didn't want to change it to `MP`. I've made these changes too.

Comment: `$arr[] = explode($c, $y[$i])[0];` isn't valid either =/

Comment: Pardon me. I haven't been using 5.3 in a while. I'm already on 7. I'm sure this should work now.

Answer (score 1):

As with Python, you can use a generator (useful when you deal with a big file and you want to preserve memory):

```
function genOrderNumbers($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($line, 'Order Number: ') === 0)
            yield rtrim(substr($line, 14));
    }
}

$fh = fopen('inputfile.txt', 'r');
if ($fh) {
    foreach (genOrderNumbers($fh) as $orderNumber)
        echo $orderNumber, PHP_EOL;
    fclose($fh);
}
```